# why can't we just upload a file and it reaches its destination without the other device downloading it?

Tags: networking, internet, download, bandwidth, tcp

when we have to view or get some content off the internet. We have to download it
on the other hand the server uploads it

So here's my question => Why can't the server simply upload the file and it reaches our computer? why do we have to use our bandwidth to download it when the server is using its own bandwidth to upload?

Comment: You downloading a file ***is the same as*** the server uploading the file. They are exactly the same operation but just viewed from different positions.

Comment: Feels like this should be migrated to ELL instead.

Comment: The server pays to upload it. You pay to download it. That's how the internet works.

Comment: At least in the US, when you're connected to municipal water and sewer, you typically pay for water twice; once to receive the water for your use, and then again for use of the public sewer system to take the water away.  It's similar.  The Internet is a collection of infrastructure to move data.  It's funded by paying to put data in and paying to take data out.  Uploading puts data in.  Downloading takes data out.

Comment: It is worth pointing out that, the server would typically, pay per byte they received and transmited.  Consumer ISPs don't typically charge per byte.

Answer (score 4):

That's two separate questions really:

> Why can't the server simply upload the file and it reaches our computer?

The process of "reaching your computer" **is** called downloading – which really means "receiving data" and nothing more. (Uploading means sending data.)

Whether it's a file or a letter or a shipment – the fact that it reaches you,  means you have received it. Therefore, if a network transfer reaches you, that by itself means you've downloaded it.

> why do we have to use our bandwidth to download it when the server is using its own bandwidth to upload?

Bandwidth does not describe energy and does not travel along with the data. Instead it describes *capacity* of the channel – the *width* of the 'road' through which data is sent.

Analogy with actual roads: If you drive from point A to point B, you have to use the road capacity at A *and* at B (and the whole distance in between, too). (And if the road at B is too narrow, you can't exactly take some spare asphalt from A and carry it with you...)

Comment: I'd be tempted to add that what many people describe as "bandwidth limits" as in "I hit my bandwidth limit this month" are actually better described and named as data allocation or data cap, they are the quantity of data you are allowed to download in a month. They have nothing to do with your effective bandwidth, which as you rightly mention is the speed at which you are able to download data.

Comment: Can someone please explain how the data is transmitted over the Internet, i am familiar with packet switching , message switching etc . do these got something to do with transmission of data?

Comment: @VasuDeo.S Watch [Warriors of the Net](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PBWhzz_Gn10)

Comment: @DavidPostill that is an entertaining clip but I doubt it will help answering the question. Although I'm curious maybe the author will have a different opinion.